# how to change table structure after data binding using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a table its data generated by ng-repeat

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list" post-repeat-directive>
        <td>{{item.col1}}</td>
        <td>{{item.col2}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to combine frist td if they have the same value in the adjacent tr after binding, but do nothing if they are different. 
I've tried to use directive

```
app.directive('postRepeatDirective', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        if (scope.$last){
            // combine if they have the same value
        }
    };
});
```

But in scope.$last, they are still {{item.col1}}, but not the value from "list". So all first td are combine to one.

What can I do?

---

**Edit**:
[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/PmeeGCO4G4tbVHvyQ5gT)

Comment: How many tds are their?

Comment: five tds, and hundreds trs

Comment: there are colspan and rowspan attributes that you need to play with in your directive... you should to change value of the spans on the basis of what is contained in it... also check [ng-cells](http://gdepourtales.github.io/ng-cells/)

Comment: @HarishR I've already done that, but it happened before data binding.

Comment: @worldask thats the reason you need directive, so that the spans are set dynamically and not before data binding...

Comment: @HarishR I've already used directive. But in scope.$last, they are still {{item.col1}}, but not the value from "list".

Comment: @worldask can you please setup a plunker...

Comment: @HarishR I've edited plurkr in my question. Sorry for taking so long to setup my plunkr. Very busy in last couple days, and I'm in China, it's hard to visit plunkr here.

Comment: I've solved it myself, but thanks all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it myself using $timeout to execute the function delay a few time then ng-repeat is done

```
if (scope.$last) {
  $timeout(function(){
    combine_table(t);
  }, 10);
}
```